Can the composite of $\mathbb Q_p$ and $\mathbb Q_\ell$ in $\mathbb C$ be $\mathbb C$?
I will motivate my question with two observations.

Consider the standard embedding $\mathbb R\to\mathbb C$. Then, for any embedding $\mathbb Q_p\to \mathbb C$, we must have that the composite of $\mathbb R$ and (the image of) $\mathbb Q_p$ is $\mathbb C$, since $\mathbb Q_p$ will contain e.g. $\sqrt{1-p}$ by Hensel's lemma.
Since $\mathbb C$ has proper subfields isomorphic to itself, it is possible to choose embeddings $\mathbb Q_p\to \mathbb C$ and $\mathbb Q_\ell\to\mathbb C$ such that their composite is not $\mathbb C$. (Of course, the same goes for $\mathbb R$ and $\mathbb Q_p$.)

So my question is: is it possible to choose embeddings $\mathbb Q_p\to\mathbb C$ and $\mathbb Q_\ell\to \mathbb C$ such that the composite of the images is $\mathbb C$? I am interested in both the cases $p\neq\ell$ and $p=\ell$.

a good strategy might be to show that the composite is not algebraically closed

Fix an enumeration of $\mathbb{C}$ as $(a_\alpha)_{\alpha<\mathfrak{c}}$ and fix algebraically independent elements $(x_\alpha)_{\alpha<\mathfrak{c}}$ in $\mathbb{Q}_p$ and $(y_\alpha)_{\alpha<\mathfrak{c}}$ in $\mathbb{Q}_\ell$.  Recursively choose elements $b_\alpha\in\mathbb{C}$ which are algebraically independent of all the $a_\beta$ for $\beta\leq\alpha$ and all the $b_\beta$ for $\beta<\alpha$.  Note then that then $a_\alpha+b_\alpha$ is also algebraically independent of $a_\beta$ for $\beta\leq\alpha$ and the $b_\beta$ for $\beta<\alpha$.  It follows that the sets $\{b_\alpha\}_{\alpha<\mathfrak{c}}$ and $\{a_\alpha+b_\alpha\}_{\alpha<\mathfrak{c}}$ are both algebraically independent. There then exist embeddings $f:\mathbb{Q}_p\to\mathbb{C}$ and $g:\mathbb{Q}_\ell\to\mathbb{C}$ such that $f(x_\alpha)=b_\alpha$ and $g(y_\alpha)=a_\alpha+b_\alpha$ for all $\alpha$.  The compositum of the images of these embeddings is then all of $\mathbb{C}$, since it contains $a_\alpha$ for all $\alpha$.
(More generally, the same argument shows that if $K$ is an algebraically closed field of infinite transcendence degree over the prime field and $L$ and $M$ are fields of the same characteristic and transcendence degree as $K$, then there are embeddings of $L$ and $M$ into $K$ whose compositum is all of $K$.)

Hi, thanks for the answer. Why can we fix continuum-many alg. ind. elements of Q_p?

@AndreaB.: The transcendence degree of any uncountable field over the prime field is equal to its cardinality.

@TorstenSchoeneberg: Oops, thanks, I wrote that a bit too hastily.  I've corrected it.
